# Gradle plugin doesn't work in Intellij IDEA (Calculate task graph)?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, gradle-plugin

The problem is that the Gradle plugin in Intellij IDEA doesn't work with my project. If I use "Gradle build" in the command line it works perfectly but if I try to build the project with the Gradle plugin in Intellij IDEA it doesn't work. It shows some error on the task "Calculate task graph". What is it?

[image]

Why it doesn't work?

Here is console output:

```
6:21:57 PM: Executing external tasks 'gradle build'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'upload-server'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.899 secs
Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'upload-server'.
6:22:01 PM: External tasks execution finished 'gradle build'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was because I used "gradle build" command in the plugin to build the project but in the gradle plugin you don't need to use "gradle" before task.
So, I run "build" command and it is working now.

Answer (score 9):

To see the error, click that icon in the upper left corner. It will toggle between console output view and that other view.

Comment: Thanks, that was really hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

I was **facing** the same problem . when I used *build.gradle(module.app)*
the version was different.

```
       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
```

*Build>clean the project* 
I saw the exact problem that was seen when the project was run.

just correct the version then run the project

```
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

add to your build.gradle. and clean your project. show your task.

```html
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```