# im getting weird error when importing onesignal and Crashlytics together in my project?

Tags: android, crashlytics, onesignal

i was using **Crashlytics** in my project and worked well , now im adding onesignal to my project and im getting error and i cant find out the exactly problem is about the version libraries or not ! thank's for any suggestion

**my Error :**

[image]

**Build.gradle(module:app) :**

**dependencies**

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.13.0'
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
implementation 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
```

[image]

**Build.gradle(Project : myapp)**

[image]

Comment: Can you add more of the error portion..

Comment: You can just clean the project and can add this `multiDexEnabled true`  below `applicationId` and try to buld again

Comment: @buzzingsilently error screen added in my post

Comment: @Amjad Khan unfortunately not worked :(

Comment: Do you have library `calculate task graph` ?

Comment: @AmjadKhan i don't know whats that ! if you mean that its the name of library i'm inserted in dependency , it's not .

Comment: May be it is plugin you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305594/gradle-plugin-doesnt-work-in-intellij-idea-calculate-task-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from your error log,

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For *input string: **" 12"***

This is happening because your String is containing white-space at the start, before 12. & String to Number conversion can not take place for white-space.

Try removing white-space like only **"12"** instead of *" 12"*.

**Update :** 
If issue persists It might be the case of `OneSignal` newer version.
Try using older version. In my case It was 3.6.0 [OneSignal](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/3.6.0).

Comment: where should i do this ?

Comment: It is not visible in snippet so can't predict. but you should look out for this.

Comment: i think it's on library and i don't added by myself in project , cause it's happened when i'm import Onesignal library

Comment: I had worked with `OneSignal` previously & was not encounter this issue. So might be the case after new release.

Comment: You can report in their forum or try using older versions.

Comment: would you say your library version ?

Comment: I guess I was using 3.6.0, https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works both.

> Crashalytics

```
   implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
      transitive = true;
   }
```

> oneSignal

```
   implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'
```

> Buildscripts

```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
        ....
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     }

     dependencies {
       .....
       classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
     }
  }
```